# What are the correct aria attributes to use for a reducing section?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a section that starts in a reduced state. There's a button that can expand it, showing more information, but the user has the same access to all the content in either case. I'm wondering what the correct WAI-ARIA attributes to use here would be? The contents are still visible and the button is within the content so `aria-expanded` doesn't seem appropriate. Is there an attribute that describes a reduced state rather than a collapsed one?

Here's a very simplified version of the code. In the real-world example, there's a tooltip that shows the text when the user hovers over the icon (represented here by the emoji). I appreciate that the trigger doesn't have an `aria-controls` attribute - I don't know if it'd be appropriate to add it, but I can easily add one.

```js
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
const trigger = document.getElementById("sidebar-toggle");

trigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("is-collapsed");
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.is-collapsed .sidebar-text {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="is-collapsed">
    <button type="button" id="sidebar-toggle">Toggle</button>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="sidebar-icon">1️⃣</span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">One</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="sidebar-icon"> 2️⃣</span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">Two</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="sidebar-icon"> 3️⃣</span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">Three</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `aria-expanded` is the correct attribute for it. The definition says: *The aria-expanded attribute is set on an element to indicate if a control is expanded or collapsed, and whether or not its child elements are displayed or hidden.* It specifically says that it is only indicates if the element is collapsed or expanded. It does not mean that all child elements have to be invisible to fulfill that rule.

Comment: @tacoshy are you sure? I'd interpret "whether or not its child elements are displayed or hidden" as binary: either the children are visible or they're hidden. Here, some of the children are hidden but some remain displayed - including the trigger.

Comment: @tacoshy that quote seems incorrect. Which definition did you take that from? The important part here is _child elements_: [`aria-expanded`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-expanded) is *not* set on the parent, but on the toggle.

Comment: @Andi from the MDN Web Docs

Comment: @JamesLong I’m confused by the tooltip. Would that be in addition to the toggled text? `aria-controls` can have _several IDs_, so you can use that to be absolutely correct. Screen readers don’t really respect it, the convention is that the collapsed or expanded element follows directly after the toggle, which is the case. I don’t know your actual contents, but the pattern seems to resemble a table?

Comment: @Andy the tooltip would show the text on hover. The real-world example is a menu: the reduced state shows the icons only, but hovering over them shows a tooltip with the text and a series of links underneath; the expanded state shows the text next to the icon and that can be clicked, revealing the series of links.

Comment: I agree that `aria-expanded` isn't quite right. You're actually expanding the "1", "2", and "3" but those aren't interactive elements so setting `aria-expanded` on them isn't right either. I think the button itself could just say "show [whatever]" then it would toggle its label to "hide [whatever]".  It'd be similar to a password field that has a "show password" toggle next to it.  The label of the button changes and `aria-expanded` isn't needed.

Comment: I disagree with previous comment. Some content is whether shown or hidden, so aria-expanded is perfectly appropriate. It doesn't make a difference if the additional content is interactive or not. I find quite weird the collapsed state where only 1,2,3 are still shown without content, but that's another question.